# custom attribute value in not saving in quote

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to save custom attribute Value In quote table But code is not working in am adding below code in my controller

```
$quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        $quote->setCustomAttribute('test')->save();
        $quote->save();
```

please help me to understand what i am doing wrong

Comment: did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, Magento's quote entity is not an EAV entity. Hence in order to make  this work, you need to have a column `custom_attribute` in the table `sales_flat_quote`.

So create a new column through an install script and then try the same code.

**Additional note:** You are triggering `save()` twice which you can avoid. Remove the last line `$quote->save();` from your code.

Comment: I already have custom_attribute in sales flat Quote Table i tried to remove last Save as well but not working

Comment: did you find the answer?